# Toast after stopping timer, how?

Tags: android, timer

How can I make a toast after stopping the timer?

```
onCreate {

//other code

myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {          
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TimerMethod();
                }

        }, 0, 1000);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AS", 455).show();

    }

private void TimerMethod()
    {
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);

    }


    private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

                rub_stat++; 
                if (rub_stat == 15){myTimer.cancel();   }                       }
    };
```

So after rub_stat reaches 15 I want to cancel the timer and make the toast appear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: why cant you do it like you did the first Toast? Like after the cancel call...

Comment: show the toast right after myTimer.cancel();

Comment: it appears instantly not after the timer that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to make a separate thread, not on the UI thread, so basically replace

```
this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
```

with a thread call, and then you can join the thread, and have that thread pause for 15 seconds, and immediately after the join then show the `Toast`.

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep (1000 * 15);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
thread.join();
this.runOnUiThread(showToast;
```

`showToast` would just be a function to show the toast.

**I haven't tested this code** out, but it should be close to what you need.

For more on `join` you can look at this blog article:

http://cnapagoda.blogspot.ca/2010/01/thread-join-method.html